# How to delete a vocabulary terms programmatically?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I want to remove all the terms from a vocab but not delete the vocab itself.

I can do it on the database, but Id rather use the api if available in D8.

```
$existingTerms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('mycustomvocab');
foreach ($existingTerms as $existingTerm) {
  // Delete vocabulary term *** This function is not available in D8 ***
  taxonomy_term_delete($existingTerm->tid);

  // Delete vocabulary - *** Not what is required ***
  /*
  $vocab = Vocabulary::load($existingTerm->vid);
  if (!is_null($vocab)) {
    $vocab->delete();
  }
  */
}
```

This is how Im doing it at the moment until I find a better solution

```
db_query("DELETE FROM {taxonomy_term_hierarchy} WHERE `tid` IN (SELECT tid FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE `vid` = :ctype)", array(':ctype' => 'mycustomvocab'));  
db_query("DELETE FROM {taxonomy_term_field_data} WHERE `vid` = :ctype", array(':ctype' => 'mycustomvocab'));
db_query("DELETE FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE `vid` = :ctype", array(':ctype' => 'mycustomvocab'));
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
  $tids = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
    ->condition('vid', 'mycustomvocab')
    ->execute();

  $controller = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  $entities = $controller->loadMultiple($tids);
  $controller->delete($entities);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just noting another approach to delete the taxonomy term individually, useful for some cases:

```
// Example to load and delete a taxonomy term
$tid = 12;
if ($term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($tid)) {
  // Delete the term itself
  $term->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*If you have access to Drupal Shell run following commands :
`drupal shell`

*Then copy and paste following

```
function truncate_vocab($vid){
    $tids = \Drupal::entityQuery("taxonomy_term")->condition("vid",$vid)->execute();
    $controller = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
    $entites = $controller->loadMultiple($tids);
    $controller->delete($entites);
}
$vocabs = taxonomy_vocabulary_get_names();
foreach($vocabs as $vid){
   truncate_vocab($vid);
}
```

I will try to make it a Drupal Shell command in future.